# When I execute my Android Application, Is there any possible to know How much memory occupy to run programme

Tags: android

I am new to android. I implementing one app in android. But I would like to know How much memory occupied When i execute my app. plz help me If any one got.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the memory usage can be a real pain, there are *MANY* factors.

But here on Stackoverflow is a [real great explanaition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813). I dont quote it because, it is the best if you read through on your own ;-)

In short: use "adb shell procrank" (but really, read the linked answer, it's a great answer ;-)